# Unhandled event loop exception (plug-in: org.eclipse.ui)

Tags: eclipse, business-objects

Does anyone knows how to overcome that problem ?The eclipse version is oxygen.it happens when I wanna check out the result of my view. Thanks in advance...
Moritz

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.businessobjects.visualization.VisualizationEngine
at com.sap.dataexplorer.ui.cvom.CVOMHelper.getPossibleGraphics(CVOMHelper.java:57)
at com.sap.dataexplorer.ui.cvom.CVOMHelper.getPossibleChartTypes(CVOMHelper.java:90)
at com.sap.dataexplorer.ui.analysis.ChartAnalysisRenderer.updatePossibleGraphics(ChartAnalysisRenderer.java:434)
at com.sap.dataexplorer.ui.analysis.ChartAnalysisRenderer.update(ChartAnalysisRenderer.java:116)
at com.sap.dataexplorer.ui.analysis.AnalysisComposite$22.executeSucceeded(AnalysisComposite.java:990)
at com.sap.dataexplorer.ui.QueryExecutorManager$2$1.run(QueryExecutorManager.java:113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4034)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3701)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  More information is needed in order to answer your question.  Please provide a minimal, complete, and viable code sample that others can use to reproduce this error.  See the following link for more info- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is `com.businessobjects.visualization.VisualizationEngine`? Eclipse can't find it.

Comment: Seems to be some addon. Try to remove/reinstall this VisualizationEngine

Comment: greg, I am trying to open some chart that's why that error shows up...however I did what Suncatcher suggested and then it works right away....thanks mate...